# Clear custom events from HockeyApp

Tags: hockeyapp

Is it possible to clear/remove existing custom events for an app in HockeyApp? If so, how do I do this?

Background: during integration of HockeyApp, I created some test events that I now wish to remove. The app isn't in production yet, so there is no concern about loss of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, no, it is not possible to remove events from HockyApp *per se* but it is possible to remove them from App Center (App Center is the "new and improved" platform that stems from HockeyApp).